# Let $\vec{x} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and define $U = \{A\vec{x} | A \in M_{mn}\}$. Show that $U=\mathbb{R}^m$ if $x \neq\vec{0}$.

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

Let $\vec{x} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and define $U = \{A\vec{x} | A \in M_{mn}\}$. It is given that $U$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Show that $U=\mathbb{R}^m$ if $x \neq\vec{0}$.

**My Attempt**

To show $U = \mathbb{R}^m$ you need to show each is a subset of another. Clearly if $U$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^m$, $U \subseteq \mathbb{R}^m$.

Now show that $\mathbb{R}^m \subseteq U$:

Let $\vec{x} \in \mathbb{R}^m$, then I need a $\vec{y} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $\vec{x} = A\vec{y}$.

$$A = (a_1, ... , a_n) \rightarrow x=Ay=(a_1y, ...,a_ny) = a_1y_1+....+a_ny_n$$

Not sure why $\vec{x}\neq \vec{0}$ though...could someone help point out the error in the proof?

Comment: I think that the matrix $A$ is not fixed throught the exercise, because if $A$ is the identity matrix, then $U \neq \mathbb{R}^m$ when $x\neq 0$

Comment: How best can I incorporate that idea into the proof ? Make it a condition of $\vec{x}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choose $b\in \mathbb{R}^m$ arbitrarily. Write $x=[x_1, \ldots, x_n]^T$. Without any loss of generality assume $x_1 \neq 0$. Let $A$ be the $m\times n$ matrix such whose first column is $\frac{1}{x_1}b$ and whose remaining $n-1$ columns are all $0$. Then $Ax=b\in U$. Since $b$ was arbitrary we have $U=\mathbb{R}^m$.

Comment: How does this work when $Ax=b$ must be true for all $A \in M_{mn}$?

Comment: If you want to show that an arbitrary $b\in \mathbb{R}^m$ belongs to $U$ you need to find *some* $A\in M_{mn}$ such that $Ax=b$

Comment: Here is another example illustrating this idea. How would you show that $(1,-1)$ belongs to the set $$\{(x^2,x^3)|x\in \mathbb{R}\}$$